How to use multi-node training with pytorch lightning
I am trying to train a neural network with pytorch lightning and I would like to split the training into two cluster nodes, with 4 gpus each. I could train on the 4 gpus of a single node, but when I try to use the second node I receive the following error:
[rank: 3] Global seed set to 0
[rank: 1] Global seed set to 0
[rank: 2] Global seed set to 0
[rank: 0] Global seed set to 0
[rank: 5] Global seed set to 0
[rank: 6] Global seed set to 0
[rank: 7] Global seed set to 0
[rank: 4] Global seed set to 0

[...]

    raise MisconfigurationException(
lightning_fabric.utilities.exceptions.MisconfigurationException: You requested gpu: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
 But your machine only has: [0, 1, 2, 3]
srun: error: lrdn0346: tasks 0-3: Exited with exit code 1
srun: error: lrdn0910: tasks 4-7: Exited with exit code 1


Here is my definition of the trainer:
trainer = pl.Trainer(accelerator=accelerator, strategy="ddp_find_unused_parameters_true", devices=8, num_nodes=2,  log_every_n_steps=20, max_epochs=conf.training.max_epochs, callbacks=[early_stop_callback, checkpoint_callback], logger=tb_logger, check_val_every_n_epoch=1)


In a previous attempt I didn't put parameters for num_nodes and devices, but it failed as well.

Which version of Pytorch Lightning are you using? According to https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/clouds/cluster_advanced.html (and it has been that way since at least 1.6.5), devices specifies not the total number of GPUs, but the number of GPUs per node. So in your case, you'd use devices=4.
